# Understanding OpenTSDB timestamp

Tags: javascript, opentsdb

I want to create a very simple collector for OpenTSDB,
For instance I'm thinking of creating a simple javascript file that writes some random values.

What I don't understand is the format of those random values.
I must do a program that writes a string, for example `metric.name timestamp value` , or it's enough that my simple program writes only a value?

Comment: Have you already implemented something in JS? How do you execute your JS code from terminal?

Comment: No, i was only thinking to install node.js. But i don't know if it would be a good solution :)

Comment: Anyway, as the shell examples use this way to represent metrics: '{ print "put proc.loadavg.1m " now " " $1 " host=" host;
     print "put proc.loadavg.5m " now " " $2 " host=" host }' maybe i should use something similar also in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is not the best option for doing this type of task, I would use Python, Bash, Perl or Ruby. I'm not an expert in JS, but hopes this example works for you.

Firstly you will need to create the file that generates the output. So **foo.js**, will generate random numbers and print them along with metric name and timestamp in seconds:

```
var randvar = Math.random();
var ts = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
print ("metric.name "+ts+" "+randvar);
```

Secondly you will need an executable file that launches **foo.js**, this file would be **foo.sh**. You have to give it execute permission `chmod +x foo.sh`. I'm running the JS code using **rhino**, you can use any other interpreter:

```
#!/bin/bash
rhino rand_tsd.js
```

Finally you have to put the files under the `tcollector/collectors/NUM/` folder where `NUM` is the interval in seconds between two executions. Then launch tcollector daemon.

Comment: Sorry Sir, after some weeks studying for exams, i'm returned to opentsdb. I don't understand one thing, why i need to use rhyno? it's not enough that i put foo.js and foo.sh inside a particular collector folder and then write on the console ./startstop/tcollector/collectors/NUMBER (where number is minute "3" for example?

Comment: As I told you I'm not an expert on javascript, I used rhino but you can use anything you want as long as when you execute it from console using whatever command you get the right output. OpenTSDB will execute your script like you would do it, does your script generate a right output well you execute? if does, OpenTSDB will work fine. Buona fortuna :)

Comment: The problem in my case is that i've created foo.js as you told, and i put it on a folder inside collectors. What i don't understand it's how  to create the shell and how execute it. You wrote " #!/bin/bash
rhino rand_tsd.js " , is that the code to put into foo.sh ?

Comment: anyway, if it's more easy and if it's possible, i know also a bit of java. So if it's possible to make a simple script that make some random values and for each value it gives me the time, i will use it. I'm not very good in understanding the shell script role, because i never used it. :) Thanks for your time!!